# How to insert text into specific position with ACE Editor from Angular Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ace-editor

I'm working on a real-time collaborative editor within [Ace](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-ace) editor, and I couldn't find any docs on inserting text at a certain position within the editor.

Actually I want to add text on cursor position when user get click on button.

I have using following code :

```
<div ui-ace="aceOptions" ng-model="content"></div>
```

And in angular controller I have used following code ,

```
 $scope.aceOptions = {
   mode : 'Javascript',
   theme : 'dreamweaver'
 };

 //content of ace editor
 $scope.content = "test";

 //user button click for adding text
 $scope.addTextOnClick = function(){
   //Here i have to get current cursor and needs to insert text
   //Which map to content and insert into it
 }
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Try using ng-bind. You cannot use ng-model on a div tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get cursor position with [Edit.getCurrentPosition](https://ace.c9.io/api/editor.html#Editor.getCursorPosition) method.

After, for example, that you can calculate place in the text with that position and insert something to that text.

I also suggest to check out [Ace docs](https://ace.c9.io/#nav=api).

Here is how to get Editor instance: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-ace#ace-instance-direct-access.

> the $scope.aceLoaded function will be called with the Ace Editor instance as first argument

Check out example below this header.

Comment: Yeah I have used that , sorry but please tell me how to get that I'd of editor because I have used as directive

Comment: I already said: try to read the docs. I updated my answer with how to get editor instance.

Comment: Thanks , Got the solution